# Number of permutations of order m

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, permutations

Is there a closed form for the number of permutations (on n letters) that have order m? If not, is there a tight upper bound?

Comment: I doubt there is a closed form.  If you decompose the permutation into cycles, each cycle length must divide $m$ and the LCM of the cycle lengths must be $m$ (which enforces the first condition).

Comment: This article will be of interest: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landau%27s_function